# instafeed.js not working because of CORS policy

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, instagram-api

I'm trying to use an API which returns me a JSON so I can use it on my function.

**Imports**

I'm importing **Jquery**, **instafeed.min.js** and the **API (instant-tokens.com)**.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/instafeed.js/1.3.2/instafeed.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-CoWJ3qoyvZZrGHIctI7xjuAyhg2MCZfBZ8P7PjOBA+Xp2N/xl6YUxxmE+aV4w0056tfemwyseDhf2nXlEgAF2A=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    // this one is in the head section

    <script src="https://ig.instant-tokens.com/users/133af082-bd46-416f-8d95-b6ca28a08bee/instagram/17841406882807948/token.js?userSecret=slqh9w7letquro8mj056yi"></script>
```

**Instafeed script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            var instantTokenApiUrl = 'https://ig.instant-tokens.com/users/133af082-bd46-416f-8d95-b6ca28a08bee/instagram/17841406882807948/token.js?userSecret=slqh9w7letquro8mj056yi'

            $.ajax({
                url: instantTokenApiUrl,
                dataType: 'json',
            })
                .done(function (response) {

                    if (!response.Token) {
                        console.log('Error :: ', response);
                    } else {
                        var feed = new Instafeed({
                            accessToken: response.Token
                        });
                        feed.run();
                    }
                });

        });
</script>
```

I'm trying to do what's in this post: https://github.com/codingbadger/instant-tokens.com/wiki/3.-Instafeed.js-Demo

But my feed still isn't displaying, and it gives me these CORS errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ig.instant-tokens.com/users/133af082-bd46-416f-8d95-b6ca28a08bee/instagram/17841406882807948/token.js?userSecret=slqh9w7letquro8mj056yi' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET https://ig.instant-tokens.com/users/133af082-bd46-416f-8d95-b6ca28a08bee/instagram/17841406882807948/token.js?userSecret=slqh9w7letquro8mj056yi net::ERR_FAILED

jquery.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: GET "https://ig.instant-tokens.com/users/133af082-bd46-416f-8d95-b6ca28a08bee/instagram/17841406882807948/token.js?userSecret=slqh9w7letquro8mj056yi".
```

My question is: Is there a workaround for this? I'm fairly new to ajax and JSON, so I hope people can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab to confirm no error is occuring with the request *other* than cors?

Comment: I've checked my network tab again and there's no other errors other than cors..

Comment: What is the status code of the request?

Comment: It gave me "status: 0". Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: not exactly, 0 isn't a response status code

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to this, but where can I check the status code? Normally it displays the status code in the request, but since it's throwing an error, it doesn't show the status code..

Comment: usually, even in a cors error, there's a status code returned by the server that you can see in the network tab of your dev tools. Your code doesn't have access to this value due to CORS, so any error handling in your code will display 0.

Comment: I see. Sorry for not responding sooner, but the feed doesn't display because it's being blocked by CORS, right? Is there a way to prevent it from being blocked just by the front-end side? Because, unfortunately I don't have access to the back-end...

Comment: That depends on the root cause of being blocked. You can’t make the server return proper cors headers, but you *can* ensure you are using the api the way it was meant to be used.

Comment: It’s possible that you are using the endpoint incorrectly and causing an error handler response, and for the api’s error handler to be poorly configured... but you should be able to tell from the dev tools whether or not this occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

For some reason, it worked after I added the instafeed function manually to my code, instead of linking it from an external source.

And at the end, I'm making an ajax request.

```
/* instafeed.js | v2.0.0-rc3 | https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js | License: MIT */
(function(global, factory) {
  typeof exports === "object" && typeof module !== "undefined" ? module.exports = factory() : typeof define === "function" && define.amd ? define(factory) : (global = typeof globalThis !== "undefined" ? globalThis : global || self,
    global.Instafeed = factory());
})(this, function() {
  "use strict";

  function assert(val, msg) {
    if (!val) {
      throw new Error(msg);
    }
  }

  function Instafeed(options) {
    assert(!options || typeof options === "object", "options must be an object, got " + options + " (" + typeof options + ")");
    var opts = {
      accessToken: null,
      accessTokenTimeout: 1e4,
      after: null,
      apiTimeout: 1e4,
      apiLimit: null,
      before: null,
      debug: false,
      error: null,
      filter: null,
      limit: null,
      mock: false,
      render: null,
      sort: null,
      success: null,
      target: "instafeed",
      template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img title="{{caption}}" src="{{image}}" /></a>',
      templateBoundaries: ["{{", "}}"],
      transform: null
    };
    var state = {
      running: false,
      node: null,
      token: null,
      paging: null,
      pool: []
    };
    if (options) {
      for (var optKey in opts) {
        if (typeof options[optKey] !== "undefined") {
          opts[optKey] = options[optKey];
        }
      }
    }
    assert(typeof opts.target === "string" || typeof opts.target === "object", "target must be a string or DOM node, got " + opts.target + " (" + typeof opts.target + ")");
    assert(typeof opts.accessToken === "string" || typeof opts.accessToken === "function", "accessToken must be a string or function, got " + opts.accessToken + " (" + typeof opts.accessToken + ")");
    assert(typeof opts.accessTokenTimeout === "number", "accessTokenTimeout must be a number, got " + opts.accessTokenTimeout + " (" + typeof opts.accessTokenTimeout + ")");
    assert(typeof opts.apiTimeout === "number", "apiTimeout must be a number, got " + opts.apiTimeout + " (" + typeof opts.apiTimeout + ")");
    assert(typeof opts.debug === "boolean", "debug must be true or false, got " + opts.debug + " (" + typeof opts.debug + ")");
    assert(typeof opts.mock === "boolean", "mock must be true or false, got " + opts.mock + " (" + typeof opts.mock + ")");
    assert(typeof opts.templateBoundaries === "object" && opts.templateBoundaries.length === 2 && typeof opts.templateBoundaries[0] === "string" && typeof opts.templateBoundaries[1] === "string", "templateBoundaries must be an array of 2 strings, got " + opts.templateBoundaries + " (" + typeof opts.templateBoundaries + ")");
    assert(!opts.template || typeof opts.template === "string", "template must null or string, got " + opts.template + " (" + typeof opts.template + ")");
    assert(!opts.error || typeof opts.error === "function", "error must be null or function, got " + opts.error + " (" + typeof opts.error + ")");
    assert(!opts.before || typeof opts.before === "function", "before must be null or function, got " + opts.before + " (" + typeof opts.before + ")");
    assert(!opts.after || typeof opts.after === "function", "after must be null or function, got " + opts.after + " (" + typeof opts.after + ")");
    assert(!opts.success || typeof opts.success === "function", "success must be null or function, got " + opts.success + " (" + typeof opts.success + ")");
    assert(!opts.filter || typeof opts.filter === "function", "filter must be null or function, got " + opts.filter + " (" + typeof opts.filter + ")");
    assert(!opts.transform || typeof opts.transform === "function", "transform must be null or function, got " + opts.transform + " (" + typeof opts.transform + ")");
    assert(!opts.sort || typeof opts.sort === "function", "sort must be null or function, got " + opts.sort + " (" + typeof opts.sort + ")");
    assert(!opts.render || typeof opts.render === "function", "render must be null or function, got " + opts.render + " (" + typeof opts.render + ")");
    assert(!opts.limit || typeof opts.limit === "number", "limit must be null or number, got " + opts.limit + " (" + typeof opts.limit + ")");
    assert(!opts.apiLimit || typeof opts.apiLimit === "number", "apiLimit must null or number, got " + opts.apiLimit + " (" + typeof opts.apiLimit + ")");
    this._state = state;
    this._options = opts;
  }
  Instafeed.prototype.run = function run() {
    var scope = this;
    this._debug("run", "options", this._options);
    this._debug("run", "state", this._state);
    if (this._state.running) {
      this._debug("run", "already running, skipping");
      return false;
    }
    this._start();
    this._debug("run", "getting dom node");
    if (typeof this._options.target === "string") {
      this._state.node = document.getElementById(this._options.target);
    } else {
      this._state.node = this._options.target;
    }
    if (!this._state.node) {
      this._fail(new Error("no element found with ID " + this._options.target));
      return false;
    }
    this._debug("run", "got dom node", this._state.node);
    this._debug("run", "getting access token");
    this._getAccessToken(function onTokenReceived(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        scope._debug("onTokenReceived", "error", err);
        scope._fail(new Error("error getting access token: " + err.message));
        return;
      }
      scope._debug("onTokenReceived", "got token", token);
      scope._state.token = token;
      scope._showNext(function onNextShown(err) {
        if (err) {
          scope._debug("onNextShown", "error", err);
          scope._fail(err);
          return;
        }
        scope._finish();
      });
    });
    return true;
  };
  Instafeed.prototype.hasNext = function hasNext() {
    var paging = this._state.paging;
    var pool = this._state.pool;
    this._debug("hasNext", "paging", paging);
    this._debug("hasNext", "pool", pool.length, pool);
    return pool.length > 0 || paging && typeof paging.next === "string";
  };
  Instafeed.prototype.next = function next() {
    var scope = this;
    if (!scope.hasNext()) {
      scope._debug("next", "hasNext is false, skipping");
      return false;
    }
    if (scope._state.running) {
      scope._debug("next", "already running, skipping");
      return false;
    }
    scope._start();
    scope._showNext(function onNextShown(err) {
      if (err) {
        scope._debug("onNextShown", "error", err);
        scope._fail(err);
        return;
      }
      scope._finish();
    });
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._showNext = function showNext(callback) {
    var scope = this;
    var url = null;
    var poolItems = null;
    var hasLimit = typeof this._options.limit === "number";
    scope._debug("showNext", "pool", scope._state.pool.length, scope._state.pool);
    if (scope._state.pool.length > 0) {
      if (hasLimit) {
        poolItems = scope._state.pool.splice(0, scope._options.limit);
      } else {
        poolItems = scope._state.pool.splice(0);
      }
      scope._debug("showNext", "items from pool", poolItems.length, poolItems);
      scope._debug("showNext", "updated pool", scope._state.pool.length, scope._state.pool);
      if (scope._options.mock) {
        scope._debug("showNext", "mock enabled, skipping render");
      } else {
        try {
          scope._renderData(poolItems);
        } catch (renderErr) {
          callback(renderErr);
          return;
        }
      }
      callback(null);
    } else {
      if (scope._state.paging && typeof scope._state.paging.next === "string") {
        url = scope._state.paging.next;
      } else {
        url = "https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=caption,id,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username&access_token=" + scope._state.token;
        if (!scope._options.apiLimit && typeof scope._options.limit === "number") {
          scope._debug("showNext", "no apiLimit set, falling back to limit", scope._options.apiLimit, scope._options.limit);
          url = url + "&limit=" + scope._options.limit;
        } else if (typeof scope._options.apiLimit === "number") {
          scope._debug("showNext", "apiLimit set, overriding limit", scope._options.apiLimit, scope._options.limit);
          url = url + "&limit=" + scope._options.apiLimit;
        }
      }
      scope._debug("showNext", "making request", url);
      scope._makeApiRequest(url, function onResponseReceived(err, data) {
        var processed = null;
        if (err) {
          scope._debug("onResponseReceived", "error", err);
          callback(new Error("api request error: " + err.message));
          return;
        }
        scope._debug("onResponseReceived", "data", data);
        scope._success(data);
        scope._debug("onResponseReceived", "setting paging", data.paging);
        scope._state.paging = data.paging;
        try {
          processed = scope._processData(data);
          scope._debug("onResponseReceived", "processed data", processed);
          if (processed.unused && processed.unused.length > 0) {
            scope._debug("onResponseReceived", "saving unused to pool", processed.unused.length, processed.unused);
            for (var i = 0; i < processed.unused.length; i++) {
              scope._state.pool.push(processed.unused[i]);
            }
          }
        } catch (processErr) {
          callback(processErr);
          return;
        }
        if (scope._options.mock) {
          scope._debug("onResponseReceived", "mock enabled, skipping append");
        } else {
          try {
            scope._renderData(processed.items);
          } catch (renderErr) {
            callback(renderErr);
            return;
          }
        }
        callback(null);
      });
    }
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._processData = function processData(data) {
    var hasTransform = typeof this._options.transform === "function";
    var hasFilter = typeof this._options.filter === "function";
    var hasSort = typeof this._options.sort === "function";
    var hasLimit = typeof this._options.limit === "number";
    var transformedFiltered = [];
    var limitDelta = null;
    var dataItem = null;
    var transformedItem = null;
    var filterResult = null;
    var unusedItems = null;
    this._debug("processData", "hasFilter", hasFilter, "hasTransform", hasTransform, "hasSort", hasSort, "hasLimit", hasLimit);
    if (typeof data !== "object" || typeof data.data !== "object" || data.data.length <= 0) {
      return null;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
      dataItem = this._getItemData(data.data[i]);
      if (hasTransform) {
        try {
          transformedItem = this._options.transform(dataItem);
          this._debug("processData", "transformed item", dataItem, transformedItem);
        } catch (err) {
          this._debug("processData", "error calling transform", err);
          throw new Error("error in transform: " + err.message);
        }
      } else {
        transformedItem = dataItem;
      }
      if (hasFilter) {
        try {
          filterResult = this._options.filter(transformedItem);
          this._debug("processData", "filter item result", transformedItem, filterResult);
        } catch (err) {
          this._debug("processData", "error calling filter", err);
          throw new Error("error in filter: " + err.message);
        }
        if (filterResult) {
          transformedFiltered.push(transformedItem);
        }
      } else {
        transformedFiltered.push(transformedItem);
      }
    }
    if (hasSort) {
      try {
        transformedFiltered.sort(this._options.sort);
      } catch (err) {
        this._debug("processData", "error calling sort", err);
        throw new Error("error in sort: " + err.message);
      }
    }
    if (hasLimit) {
      limitDelta = transformedFiltered.length - this._options.limit;
      this._debug("processData", "checking limit", transformedFiltered.length, this._options.limit, limitDelta);
      if (limitDelta > 0) {
        unusedItems = transformedFiltered.slice(transformedFiltered.length - limitDelta);
        this._debug("processData", "unusedItems", unusedItems.length, unusedItems);
        transformedFiltered.splice(transformedFiltered.length - limitDelta, limitDelta);
      }
    }
    return {
      items: transformedFiltered,
      unused: unusedItems
    };
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._extractTags = function extractTags(str) {
    var exp = /#([^\s]+)/gi;
    var badChars = /[~`!@#$%^&*\(\)\-\+={}\[\]:;"'<>\?,\./|\\\s]+/i;
    var tags = [];
    var match = null;
    if (typeof str === "string") {
      while ((match = exp.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (badChars.test(match[1]) === false) {
          tags.push(match[1]);
        }
      }
    }
    return tags;
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._getItemData = function getItemData(data) {
    var type = null;
    var image = null;
    switch (data.media_type) {
      case "IMAGE":
        type = "image";
        image = data.media_url;
        break;

      case "VIDEO":
        type = "video";
        image = data.thumbnail_url;
        break;

      case "CAROUSEL_ALBUM":
        type = "album";
        image = data.media_url;
        break;
    }
    return {
      caption: data.caption,
      tags: this._extractTags(data.caption),
      id: data.id,
      image: image,
      link: data.permalink,
      model: data,
      timestamp: data.timestamp,
      type: type,
      username: data.username
    };
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._renderData = function renderData(items) {
    var hasTemplate = typeof this._options.template === "string";
    var hasRender = typeof this._options.render === "function";
    var item = null;
    var itemHtml = null;
    var container = null;
    var html = "";
    this._debug("renderData", "hasTemplate", hasTemplate, "hasRender", hasRender);
    if (typeof items !== "object" || items.length <= 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      item = items[i];
      if (hasRender) {
        try {
          itemHtml = this._options.render(item, this._options);
          this._debug("renderData", "custom render result", item, itemHtml);
        } catch (err) {
          this._debug("renderData", "error calling render", err);
          throw new Error("error in render: " + err.message);
        }
      } else if (hasTemplate) {
        itemHtml = this._basicRender(item);
      }
      if (itemHtml) {
        html = html + itemHtml;
      } else {
        this._debug("renderData", "render item did not return any content", item);
      }
    }
    this._debug("renderData", "html content", html);
    container = document.createElement("div");
    container.innerHTML = html;
    this._debug("renderData", "container", container, container.childNodes.length, container.childNodes);
    while (container.childNodes.length > 0) {
      this._debug("renderData", "appending child", container.childNodes[0]);
      this._state.node.appendChild(container.childNodes[0]);
    }
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._basicRender = function basicRender(data) {
    var exp = new RegExp(this._options.templateBoundaries[0] + "([\\s\\w.]+)" + this._options.templateBoundaries[1], "gm");
    var template = this._options.template;
    var match = null;
    var output = "";
    var substr = null;
    var lastIndex = 0;
    var keyPath = null;
    var keyPathValue = null;
    while ((match = exp.exec(template)) !== null) {
      keyPath = match[1];
      substr = template.slice(lastIndex, match.index);
      output = output + substr;
      keyPathValue = this._valueForKeyPath(keyPath, data);
      if (keyPathValue) {
        output = output + keyPathValue.toString();
      }
      lastIndex = exp.lastIndex;
    }
    if (lastIndex < template.length) {
      substr = template.slice(lastIndex, template.length);
      output = output + substr;
    }
    return output;
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._valueForKeyPath = function valueForKeyPath(keyPath, data) {
    var exp = /([\w]+)/gm;
    var match = null;
    var key = null;
    var lastValue = data;
    while ((match = exp.exec(keyPath)) !== null) {
      if (typeof lastValue !== "object") {
        return null;
      }
      key = match[1];
      lastValue = lastValue[key];
    }
    return lastValue;
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._fail = function fail(err) {
    var didHook = this._runHook("error", err);
    if (!didHook && console && typeof console.error === "function") {
      console.error(err);
    }
    this._state.running = false;
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._start = function start() {
    this._state.running = true;
    this._runHook("before");
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._finish = function finish() {
    this._runHook("after");
    this._state.running = false;
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._success = function success(data) {
    this._runHook("success", data);
    this._state.running = false;
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._makeApiRequest = function makeApiRequest(url, callback) {
    var called = false;
    var scope = this;
    var apiRequest = null;
    var callbackOnce = function callbackOnce(err, value) {
      if (!called) {
        called = true;
        callback(err, value);
      }
    };
    apiRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    apiRequest.ontimeout = function apiRequestTimedOut() {
      callbackOnce(new Error("api request timed out"));
    };
    apiRequest.onerror = function apiRequestOnError() {
      callbackOnce(new Error("api connection error"));
    };
    apiRequest.onload = function apiRequestOnLoad(event) {
      var contentType = apiRequest.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
      var responseJson = null;
      scope._debug("apiRequestOnLoad", "loaded", event);
      scope._debug("apiRequestOnLoad", "response status", apiRequest.status);
      scope._debug("apiRequestOnLoad", "response content type", contentType);
      if (contentType.indexOf("application/json") >= 0) {
        try {
          responseJson = JSON.parse(apiRequest.responseText);
        } catch (err) {
          scope._debug("apiRequestOnLoad", "json parsing error", err, apiRequest.responseText);
          callbackOnce(new Error("error parsing response json"));
          return;
        }
      }
      if (apiRequest.status !== 200) {
        if (responseJson && responseJson.error) {
          callbackOnce(new Error(responseJson.error.code + " " + responseJson.error.message));
        } else {
          callbackOnce(new Error("status code " + apiRequest.status));
        }
        return;
      }
      callbackOnce(null, responseJson);
    };
    apiRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    apiRequest.timeout = this._options.apiTimeout;
    apiRequest.send();
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._getAccessToken = function getAccessToken(callback) {
    var called = false;
    var scope = this;
    var timeoutCheck = null;
    var callbackOnce = function callbackOnce(err, value) {
      if (!called) {
        called = true;
        clearTimeout(timeoutCheck);
        callback(err, value);
      }
    };
    if (typeof this._options.accessToken === "function") {
      this._debug("getAccessToken", "calling accessToken as function");
      timeoutCheck = setTimeout(function accessTokenTimeoutCheck() {
        scope._debug("getAccessToken", "timeout check", called);
        callbackOnce(new Error("accessToken timed out"), null);
      }, this._options.accessTokenTimeout);
      try {
        this._options.accessToken(function accessTokenReceiver(err, value) {
          scope._debug("getAccessToken", "received accessToken callback", called, err, value);
          callbackOnce(err, value);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        this._debug("getAccessToken", "error invoking the accessToken as function", err);
        callbackOnce(err, null);
      }
    } else {
      this._debug("getAccessToken", "treating accessToken as static", typeof this._options.accessToken);
      callbackOnce(null, this._options.accessToken);
    }
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._debug = function debug() {
    var args = null;
    if (this._options.debug && console && typeof console.log === "function") {
      args = [].slice.call(arguments);
      args[0] = "[Instafeed] [" + args[0] + "]";
      console.log.apply(null, args);
    }
  };
  Instafeed.prototype._runHook = function runHook(hookName, data) {
    var success = false;
    if (typeof this._options[hookName] === "function") {
      try {
        this._options[hookName](data);
        success = true;
      } catch (err) {
        this._debug("runHook", "error calling hook", hookName, err);
      }
    }
    return success;
  };
  return Instafeed;
});

  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://ig.instant-tokens.com/users/133af082-bd46-416f-8d95-b6ca28a08bee/instagram/17841406882807948/token?userSecret=slqh9w7letquro8mj056yi',

    success: function(response) {
      var feed = new Instafeed({
        target: 'instafeed',
        accessToken: response.Token, // Access token from json response
      });
      feed.run();
    },
  });
```

Thanks for all the suggestions, I really appreciate it!